# Next.js doesn't match url with query param for redirect

Tags: redirect, next.js

I've set a redirect that includes query params in Next.js 13 (inside `next.config.js`), but it doesn't work. Other redirects (the ones without query params) work fine:

```js
{
  source: '/old-url/post\\?id=2333',
  destination: '/new-url/actual-slug-of-post',
  permanent: true,
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this is:

```js
{
  source: '/old-url',
  has: [
    {
      type: 'query',
      key: 'id',
      value: '123',
    },
  ]
  ...
}
```

[Next.js Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/redirects#header-cookie-and-query-matching)